How to add a center for the next two months if there is an order the previous two months
My manager wants me count each center that has an order.  If a center make one order within the beginning of the last two months, it is considered active for the next two months from the month that it made an order.  Example: if center 'AR238' made an order in February then it is considered active for the next two months.  So it is active until April if it does not make another order in march or April.  I am trying to count each active center for each month, compounding from the previous months.  So if a center made an order in February I need to be able to count that for Feb, Mar, and April.  Please assist on how to do that.
SELECT DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(dmeorderdate) , 0 ) - 1 ) as Month, count(distinct 
DmeOrderNumberDisplay) as NPWT_Order_Volume,  count(distinct CenterCode) as NPWT_Active_Centers
FROM [AtHome].[Reporting].[WoundQOrderDetails] w
left join[AtHome].[Reporting].[DimCenter] c on c.CenterSK = w.CenterSK
where DmeOrderDate between '2024-01-01' and GETDATE()
and DmeSignedByProvider = 1
and OrderType = 'NPWT'
and CenterCode is not null
group by DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(dmeorderdate) , 0 ) - 1 ),MONTH(dmeorderdate)
order by MONTH(dmeorderdate)


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

To count each active center for each month, compounding from the previous months, you can use a combination of window functions and conditional aggregation. Here's an updated query:
WITH ActiveCenters AS (
  SELECT 
    CenterCode,
    DATEADD(mm, 2, DATE_TRUNC('month', dmeorderdate)) AS ActiveUntil
  FROM 
    [AtHome].[Reporting].[WoundQOrderDetails] w
  LEFT JOIN 
    [AtHome].[Reporting].[DimCenter] c ON c.CenterSK = w.CenterSK
  WHERE 
    DmeOrderDate BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND GETDATE()
    AND DmeSignedByProvider = 1
    AND OrderType = 'NPWT'
    AND CenterCode IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
  DATE_NAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(a.ActiveUntil), 0) - 1) AS Month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.CenterCode) AS NPWT_Active_Centers
FROM 
  ActiveCenters a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('month', dmeorderdate) AS Month
    FROM 
      [AtHome].[Reporting].[WoundQOrderDetails]
    WHERE 
      DmeOrderDate BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND GETDATE()
  ) m
WHERE 
  a.ActiveUntil >= m.Month
GROUP BY 
  DATE_NAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(a.ActiveUntil), 0) - 1)
ORDER BY 
  MONTH(a.ActiveUntil)


It keep telling me that DATETRUNC is not a built in function

The query you sent me, it gives me a syntax error saying datetrunc is not a recognized built_in function name.
